# c# - Check if string ends with 4 numbers

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I'm trying to figure out the best way to determine if a `string` ends with exactly 4 numbers.  The number range would be from 0000-9999.

eg. I have a string that could be either "MVI_2546" or something like "FILETEST".

I need to parse that string and essentially return a `true` or `false` value depending on whether it ends in exactly 4 numbers or not.

Comment: Regex.Match(yourString, "\d{4}$").Success

Comment: Correction: `Regex.Match(yourString, @"\d{4}$").Success`

Comment: Haha found out I needed that @ symbol just before you posted this.  This works exactly as I needed it to. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Added this as an answer so you can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Regex.Match` can be used to test a string against a regular expression. It returns a Match-object where the Success property shows if a match was made.

```
Regex.Match(yourString, @"\d{4}$").Success
```

Use this in your test to see if `yourString` ends in four digits.

Regards

Comment: Just a note, to use `Regex` you need to use `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
\d{4}$
```

`\d` matches a digit, the `{4}` quantifier states that there must be `4` of the previous token (`4` digits) and `$` defines the string end.

An example of using `$`:

```
# RegEx foo
foo       # Match
barfoo    # Match
foobar    # Match

# RegEx foo$
foo       # Match
barfoo    # Match
foobar    # No Match
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/eA2eD5/1)</kbd>

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
string str = "MVI_2546";

bool match =
    str.Length >= 4 && //Make sure that the string has at least 4 characters
    str.Substring(str.Length - 4) //Check that the last 4 characters
        .All(char.IsDigit); //are all digits.
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the string for the last 4 numbers

Try to turn those numbers into an integer

If an error is thrown -> last 4 digits are not a number
If it works -> last 4 digits are a number, and you will have that int to use.

Answer (score 0):

regex:

```
\b(\d\d\d)\b
```

---

```
C:\\Users\\UKS\\Desktop\\New folder\\004   // true
C:\\Users\\UKS\\Desktop\\New folder\\005   // true
C:\\Users\\UKS\\Desktop\\New folder\\00478 // false
```